# How to create Editable AutoCompleteTextview within Listview in android

Tags: android, listview, autocomplete

I am developing one application in which I am having one listview .In that  each row is having one textview and one AutoCompleteTextview. now what I want is to make that autocompletetextview editable i.e once when my list is populated with some data in it I want to edit some of the autocompletetexviews and then send updated data to the server.Is there any solution for that? I wasted my 2 days on that and I need this very urgently.

here is my customAdapter's getview() method. I can successfully populate data within listview .and I have added "addOnTextChangedListener" to the autocomletetextview. but when I filtered data it cannot set to the auotocompletetext i.e  autocomtextview.settext(filtereddata) is not performing.I am getting filtered text in onTextChanged() In my code i wrote this but I dont know actually where to put this.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_applwizard_extuser_listrow,null);


    TextView appl_Name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ext_app_name);

    auto_brand_Name=(AutoCompleteTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ext_auto_brand_txt);
    auto_brand_Name.setFocusable(true);
    auto_brand_Name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    ToggleButton toggle_status=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ext_toggle_cover);
    LinearLayout ll_save_btn=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_ext_btn_appsubmit);

    try
    {

        appl_Name.setText(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getAppliance_Name().toString());

        if(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getStatus()==true)
        {
            toggle_status.setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            toggle_status.setChecked(false);
        }


        if(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getBrand_Id()!=0)
        {
            String brand_name=null;
            brand_name=dbHandler.getBrand_id(String.valueOf(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getBrand_Id()));
            Log.d("brand name", brand_name);

            auto_brand_Name.setText(brand_name);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("brand name", "no brand");

        }


        try
        {
        auto_brand_Name.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                 String selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                 //auto_brand_Name.setText(selection);

                 Log.d("adpter value..",""+parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString());

                 try
                 {
                    AutoCompleteTextView brnd=(AutoCompleteTextView)view;
                    //Log.d( "text value.....",brnd.getText().toString());
                    brnd.setText(filteredVal);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        auto_brand_Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) 
            {
                if(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getAppliance_TypeId()!=0)
                {
                    String app_name=null;
                    app_name=dbHandler.getApp_id(String.valueOf(alApplianceDetails.get(position).getAppliance_TypeId()));

                    appliance=app_name;
                    Log.d("app_name",app_name);

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("app_name", "No App");
                }

                alBrands.clear();

                getBrand();                 
                for(int i=0;i<alBrand_Common_Objects.size();i++)
                {                   
                    alBrands.add(alBrand_Common_Objects.get(i).getcommon_name());

                }

                Log.d("brands_list", alBrands.toString());
                aaBrand =new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, alBrands);

                auto_brand_Name.setThreshold(1);
                auto_brand_Name.setAdapter(aaBrand);
                auto_brand_Name.postInvalidate();
                auto_brand_Name.invalidate();
                auto_brand_Name.showDropDown();

                aaBrand.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                //aaBrand.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
            {
                Log.d("filtered value...", s.toString());
                filteredVal=s.toString();

                //auto_brand_Name.setText(s.toString());

            }



            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
            {
                try
                {
                //auto_brand_Name.setText(filteredVal);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: We really need more details on what you can't get to work. Post errors and code examples. Only thing I can say off your text is that EditText is editable by default, which TextView is not.

Comment: Yes,we can do. when we click on the list view in some position, then we can goto new activity there we can edit what we want and finally we put submit button to submit the data and store into server based position. If your getting any error then post the log-cat which type of error your getting.

Comment: I edited my question .Now see this question

Answer (score 0):

You want to edit your data after selecting a row of list view and it will update on server side also.

1. Create list view and populate data.
2. Tap on any row and you will open new activity or popup which contain edit text with your actual data.
3. You can edit that data or cancel
4. On Update your data will be update on server via API. and adapter also.
5. On activity back or Popup dismiss refresh your adapter by calling notifyDataSetChanged();
6. On cancel your list will be same.

Comment: I saw your code also. please refer above way to achieve this. I thing, each row have autocompltetextview and synching with server also is more complex just for a small task.